# SQL - select 5 columns where 3 are distinct using multiple JOINs

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, distinct

I searched Stack Overflow before asking and looked through the 5 most relevant questions, but they did not seem to answer this.

I need to select 5 columns from a table using multiple INNER JOINs, but I only want to get the records where 3 of the 5 columns are distinct.  If I use:

```
              "select DISTINCT pos_segments.pos, ",
                       "       pos_segments.org, ",
                       "       pos_segments.obj, ",
                       "       pos_segments.proja, ",
                       "       pos_segments.eff_dt ",
                       "  from pos_segments ",
                   "INNER JOIN PersonnelPositions ",
                           "ON pos_segments.pos = PersonnelPositions.Position ",
                          "AND pos_segments.eff_dt = PersonnelPositions.EffectiveDate ",
                   "INNER JOIN Accounts ",
                           "ON PersonnelPositions.PayrollGLAccountId = Accounts.Id ",
                       " WHERE <where clause here>
```

I get back over 22k records.  I need to get the pos_segments columns only where the combination of the following three columns are distinct:

```
pos_segments.pos, pos_segments.proja, pos_segments.eff_dt
```

These three columns taken together serve as a unique key for this table.  How can I only get back the records which are distinct based on the combination of these three columns?

P.S. - we are using MS SQL Server

Thanks!

Comment: Then which value do you want for the other two columns? First (need to define an order), MIN, MAX???

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what you mean by "which value do you want...".  There is only one value in each column for each row.  I want a set of records which contains data from each of the five columns.  I should get one record for each row in the pos_segments table which satisfy my WHERE clause.  I omitted the WHERE clause because it is irrelevant and will change depending on context in my program..

Comment: Right but if you have two row where pos = 1, pos_segments = 1 and eff_dt = november 5 but different values in org and obj you need to tell the sql engine which value you want since you are only returning a single now.

Comment: Ahh yes I see what you mean now, thanks for clearing that up!  The fact that you asked me that makes me think that maybe my approach is wrong and maybe I am trying to force this query into working with SELECT DISTINCT when in reality it might be better to re-structure the query in some other way.  The short answer to your question is "I don't know", but I think that we could maybe just arbitrarily decide which values we want in those cases.

Comment: Then you could simply wrap those other two columns with MIN. That would at least work well enough that you can do some testing to see if that would work.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: As Sean pointed out, the ORDER BY statement is not optional. I never tried without it so I wasn't sure. And it would appear that the code block below is more of a suggestion than a copy paste so take it with a grain of salt. However, this approach should still work with some tweaking to fit your application. Since you mentioned that it may be arbitrary which distinct row is grabbed, you can put either of the other two columns after the ORDER BY statement.

I very recently needed to solve a very similar issue. I was able to accomplish what I needed by using a partition in conjunction with a where statement. You code would be modified to look like this:

```
 "select * from ("
          "select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pos_segments.pos,
                       pos_segments.proja, pos_segments.eff_dt ORDER BY pos_segments.org) 
                       AS row_num_throwaway"
                   "       pos_segments.pos, ",
                   "       pos_segments.org, ",
                   "       pos_segments.obj, ",
                   "       pos_segments.proja, ",
                   "       pos_segments.eff_dt ",
                   "  from pos_segments ",
               "INNER JOIN PersonnelPositions ",
                       "ON pos_segments.pos = PersonnelPositions.Position ",
                      "AND pos_segments.eff_dt = PersonnelPositions.EffectiveDate ",
               "INNER JOIN Accounts ",
                       "ON PersonnelPositions.PayrollGLAccountId = Accounts.Id ",
                   " WHERE <where clause here>)"
  "WHERE row_num_throwaway = 1"
```

That first row_number partition line just finds distinct versions of the three columns specified and assigns a row number that counts up as more instances of that distinct group are found. By only looking where row_num_throwaway = 1, you are only getting the first time that combo is present. To ensure you retrieve the correct entry, you can always add an ORDER BY statement where I showed with the stars.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ORDER BY is not optional, it is required. And as posted this will never work because you have a mismatch of t-sql and the OP's programming code.

Comment: Isn't t-sql the language used for MS SQL Server? That is what the poster listed as what they are using

Comment: Yes but you can't wrap t-sql in double quote like this. :)

Comment: Ahhhh. Thank you for the clarification. I was wondering why the poster had used quotes as I had never seen it written like that.